# C# Catching exception which is occurring on ThreadPool

Tags: c#, exception, threadpool

I am investigating some crashes in my application caused by a Win32 exception, and I have narrowed it down that it must be occurring in the threadpool which is taking care of the `EventLog.EntryWrittenEventHandler` event handler in my application. I set this up like this:

```
// Create the event log monitor
eventLog.Log = "Application";
eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
eventLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(EventLogMonitor);
```

`EventLogMonitor` is the handler for my event. I am wondering does anybody have any ideas as to where I could find out whats causing this exception. It seems that to listen for events a `ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback` is being set up, which wouldn't have any of my code on it, and if the exception is occurring on this I just cant see how to deal with this problem. Any help is really appreciated!!

Here is the output of !clrstack in WinDBG:

```
0:008> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x106c (8)
ESP       EIP     
049df1c8 7756f871 [HelperMethodFrame: 049df1c8] 
049df26c 73ce6fa0 System.Diagnostics.EventLog.get_OldestEntryNumber()
049df27c 73bf24ed System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CompletionCallback(System.Object)
049df2c4 73bf0fe4 System.Diagnostics.EventLog.StaticCompletionCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
049df2f4 744fc3b8 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context(System.Object, Boolean)
049df300 744fc373 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context_f(System.Object)
049df304 7400027f System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
049df31c 744fc477 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
049df4ac 74991b5c [GCFrame: 049df4ac]
```

In case it helps, my application is just checking the event ID of every entry written to the event log, and if it matches one of a certain set of ID's then I log it. The crashes happen quiet rarely, and the exception is a System.ComponentModel.Win32 exception with message 'Access is denied'. That sounds like it could be a permissions issue but why would it work ok for a certain period and then suddenly crash with this.

Comment: What kind of exception is it?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32 exception with message 'Access is denied'. The strange thing is it happens very rarely, my application which runs as a service can go for days and then suddenly it crashes with this..

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to create your own, never previously used event source, and that it crashes only then?

Comment: Hard to explain, EventLog.CompletionCallback() catches all exceptions.  Is this just a first chance exception?  What is the actual exception message text?  Do you use the SynchronizingObject property?

Comment: No, I am not creating any event sources

Comment: Out of curiosity, and to support Hans' and my doubts (see my answer Update #2), could you show the output of `!eestack` for the relevant thread (i.e. including the native frames).

Comment: @HansPassant, first chance exception would be my current guess either, however the OP says the "application crashes". Strange.

Comment: @Christian.K The output of !eestack up as far as where I see the exception is located at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/765e45c4-12fd-4595-ad4c-2b8bdd8d1f24/#67d838a5-de1e-4085-929e-c055c05b2602 where I asked this question some time ago. The exception message text is 'Access is denied'. How would I check if it is a first chance exception? Also you are right, I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: @Jim Very simply spoken, every exception bubbles twice through the call stack. The first chance is typically used by a debugger to observe the exception when happening, but before the stack actuallz unwound. The second chance is then "used" by catch-blocks (and stack unwinding), and if there is none up the call stack the exception basically goes unhandled. So in this case, by first-chance, we mean that the exception is only "observable" while a debugger is attached. I wonder why you seem to have an app crash (i.e. unhandled 2nd chance exception), when the EventLog code has a catch-block.

Comment: @Christian.K First of all Christian.K thanks a million for your help on this, I have been trying to figure this out for a while and you and Hans Passant have provided a good deal of insight! This seems to be very unusual, the exception should be caught by the catch in the Event log code - but its not? Is there anywhere I can see this EventLog code I wonder? Is the catch in there rethrowing the error or anything?

Comment: You could use the [.net framework reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) or a decompiler like Reflector, dotPeek from JetBrains or ILSpy.

Comment: Do you think there is much point in me trying to ask Microsoft about this? Do they help people look into issues like this?

Comment: You could try Process Monitor from sysinternals and filter it for your application process name. This might narrow things down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (it would help if you pass the stacktrace that leads you to the conclusion that the exception is happening inside a threadpool thread), then just wrap your code of EventLogMonitor in a try/catch block.

Example:

```
void EventLogHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   try
   {
      // Your original code.
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Log or Write "ex" to the console. Set a breakpoint, whatever.

      throw;
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**: after your update it looks as if the exception is indeed not raised from inside your handler, but before it is even called inside the EventLog class.

You could try registering a handler with the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event and do your logging/handling in there. Note that this will not allow you to suppress or "change" or wrap the exception, but merely to log it somewhere for diagnostic purposes.

If you just want to inspect the exception once (or on occasion), you should try using the SOS-extension's `!PrintException` command in WinDBG.

**UPDATE 2**: after further investigation I find it rather strange that the exception bubbles up all. Your stacktrace suggests you're using .NET 3.5 (or earlier, but not 4.) and looking at the EventLog class in Reflector you can see that the whole handling of the `EventWrittenHandler`, including the preamble code that seems to cause the exception, is wrapped in one big "try/catch(Exception)/catch" block. Funny.

Comment: I have added the output of !clrstack to my question. I have actually tried what you are suggesting Christian.K and my application still crashed without firing the try/catch. The exception is occuring on some Threadpool that .NET must set up to listen for entry written events from the event log, and exceptions dont propogate across threads so I dont think this will work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Thanks for your help on this issue Christian.K, I still havent got to the bottom of this, had to pass the issue on to Microsoft, your suggestions helped a lot on investigating the issue though!

Comment: Too bad we couldn't figure this out completely. I have revisited the issue, casually, a couple of times, but didn't come up with any new ideas (which doesn't really say a lot :-).

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to `Application.ThreadException` in your Program.cs as follows to be able to catch the exceptions that are not in main thread.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleException(e);
        }
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleException(e.Exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can, use Tasks in `System.Threading.Tasks`.
2. Try, where action is performing what you want.

   ```
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
   {
       try
       {
           action();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           OnException(ex);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I dont think this will work, when you subscribe to the EventLogEntryWritten event handler a seperate ThreadPool seems to be started to monitor for entries written to the event log, it is on this ThreadPool that the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of Application this is, so in a general case, if you're having no luck, try hooking into the AppDomain in which the code is running. If you don't have multiple domains, you can try:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += Handler`

or

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Handler`